# Update a value of a row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck in update a cell value in excel based on the following scenario.

Basically, IF a value in `H2` is equal to a value in the column `E`, change the value of same row in Column `D`

Example `H2`="123456", `E4567`= "123456", THEN change `D4567` = value from cell `I2`

I am matching a value from one cell to the column via match formula.

```
=MATCH(H3; E:E; 0)
```

Based on the the above formula, I have a row number.

Then I tried the CONCAT to mimic the cell reference which i want to change.
formula `= CONCAT("D",3528)`

Now I would like to know here, how to use the above mimic row to change the value via an excel formula.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("D" & 3528)`

Comment: You can't affect the value of a cell with a formula in a different cell. You would need to write the formula in cells of Column D to have one value or another based on this condition logic like `=IF(E2=H2, E2, "Some other valuue")` in cell `D2` and copy down.

Comment: This(=INDIRECT("D" & 3528)) will provide the value of row D3528. But i have to change the value of D3528 to the value from cell I2.

Comment: I gave you an equivalent of what you were trying with `CONCAT("D",3528)`. I think what you need is suggested by @JNevill. But for clarity sake can you post a screenshot of what you exactly want?

Comment: What JNevill suggested will change the value of E2 right? But I want to change the value of D2, IF E2 =H2.

Comment: You can't change the value of D2 formulaically, unless you put a formula in D2 or put a formula that spills into D2. @JNevill's comment says "write the formula ... in cell `D2`".

Comment: BigBen - This is what I dont know how to do it and struck here.

Comment: It will be better if you post a screenshot of your query. What I feel you might need `VBA` here as per your expectations. May be i am wrong, but please do [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78161708/edit) post with some markdown data and expected output.

Comment: @codec what I was suggesting is a formula in `D2` that looks like what I wrote. That formula will only affect the value in D2. A formula CANNOT change the value in another cell. Only the cell that it's in (with the exception of spillage, but you aren't writing or needing an array formula so that has nothing to do with this). In my example `E2` value will NOT be affected. You have a very basic misunderstanding of what formulas are and how they act.

Comment: Do you mean `=INDEX(D:D;MATCH(H3; E:E; 0))` ?